# Find IDS not present in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-in

I have a bunch of md5 ids

```
6c26e28dc6484f0e998fd18b883de4c6
2bf4d0d85709c75adba13ba48011d62c
a67a5bcf329d58d2c23ed422214f66b3
...
```

Some of them are present in the table and some of them are new. How do I find which of these ids are not present in table
If I do

```
select id from items where id not iN (...)
```

it then excludes all the ids

If I do

```
select id from items where id IN (...)
```

it only gives the ids that are present and I have to programmatically find the ones not present
How do I directly get the IDS not present

**Database: postgresql**

Comment: the where not IN will return every id in the table that is not in this array, i just want the bunch of ids in the array that is not in the table

Comment: You have an answer below.  Get those ids into a table of their own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`VALUES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-values.html) clause which is a standard and available in most RDBMS:

```sql
SELECT src.id
FROM (VALUES
    ('6c26e28dc6484f0e998fd18b883de4c6'),
    ('2bf4d0d85709c75adba13ba48011d62c'),
    ('a67a5bcf329d58d2c23ed422214f66b3')
) AS src(id)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM items 
    WHERE items.id = src.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get among the bunch, those that are not present in items.
I would turn the md5 into a table with unnest and string_to_array

```
select * from
( select
unnest(string_to_array('6c26e28dc6484f0e998fd18b883de4c6,
2bf4d0d85709c75adba13ba48011d62c,
a67a5bcf329d58d2c23ed422214f66b3', ','))as md5
)  a
where not exists(select 1 from items i where id = md5)
```